# Sequence converging to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove the sequence $x_n = \frac{2n}{n^2 + 1}$ converges to zero.

Attempt proof: $x_n = \frac{2n}{n^2\left(1 + \frac1{n^2}\right)} = \frac2{n\left( 1 + \frac1{n^2}\right)}$

Now we can know $\frac2n \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Can we use the Squeeze Theorem to say the sequence also go to zero. because $\frac2n$ is dominant? 
I know how to prove it using the basic calculations, but I am not sure if I can do that here.
Please I would really appreciate any feedback. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the Squeeze Theorem, then observe that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, we have that:
$$
0 \leq \frac{2n}{n^2 + 1} \leq \frac{2n}{n^2 + 0} = \frac{2}{n}
$$
So if we already know that $\frac{2}{n} \to 0$ for large $n$, then the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Use the squeeze theorem, which is basically the same as you mention:

$$0\le\frac{2n}{n^2+1}\le\frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac2n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$